# Axon & CompletableFuture

Tags: completable-future, axon

I've faced with problems when i try to use CompletableFuture with Axon.
For example:

```
CompletableFuture future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {

            log.info("Start processing target: {}", target.toString());
            return new Event();

        }, threadPool);

future.thenAcceptAsync(event -> {
            log.info("Send Event");
            AggregateLifecycle.apply(event);
}, currentExecutor);
```

in thenAcceptAsync - AggregateLifecycle.apply(event) has unexpected behavior. Some of my @EventSourcingHandler handlers start handling event twice. Does anybody know how to fix it?

I have been reading docs and everything that i got is:

> In most cases, the DefaultUnitOfWork will provide you with the
>   functionality you need. It expects processing to happen within a
>   single thread.

so, it seems i should use somehow CurrentUnitOfWork.get/set methods but still can't understand Axon API.

Comment: From this small code snippet, it looks like you're generating and applying events asynchronously inside your aggregate, is that right? I'm trying to think of a use case where that would be used, and I can't come up with one. I'm not sure it's supported. When the AggregateLifecycle.apply() runs, the event should be persisted in the event store. The EventProcessors will then process these either synchronously or asynchronously, depending whether you're using subscribing or tracking event processors.

Comment: why it’s impossible? i want to do something separately in threadpool and then send event to continue working on result. What is the problem here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not `apply()` events asynchronously. The `apply()` method will call the aggregate's internal @EventSourcingHandler methods and schedule the event for publication when the unit of work completes (successfully).
The way Axon works with the Unit of Work (which coordinates activity of a single message handler invocation), the apply() method must be invoked in the thread that manages that Unit of Work.

If you want asynchronous publication of Events, use an Event Bus that uses an Async Transport, and use Tracking Processors.

Comment: nice, is there some example of using this approach?)

Comment: There are examples for most features in the sample projects on the AxonFramework github: https://github.com/AxonFramework

Comment: Allard, could u please explain me how to setup Event Bus that uses an Async Transport and handle events from diff. threads correctly ?

Comment: when i using config.usingTrackingProcessors(); i lost all data in fields in Aggregate class

Comment: You aggregate class should not have anything to do with tracking processors. Are you separating your models properly? Have a look at the https://github.com/AxonIQ/axon-quick-start repository. It contains some assignments to learn the basics of Axon.